# Why int.Parse(NumericUpDown.Value.ToString())?

Tags: c#

I've run into this pattern repeatedly in a project I'm working with:

```
int myIntValue = int.Parse(myNumericUpDown.Value.ToString());
```

This seems a little bit bananas to me, get a string from a decimal and then parse the string to get an int, and I wonder if there is something I'm missing that necessitates it.  Seems like it has to be deliberate.  Is there a reason that should be used rather than the obvious approach:

```
int myIntValue = (int)myNumericUpDown.Value;
```

Or:

```
int myIntValue = Convert.ToInt32(myNumericUpDown.Value);
```

Comment: Is the person who wrote that code available? Have you asked them?

Comment: I would do it as you. :-)

Comment: I've seen a lot worse. Submit the original code to TheDailyWTF and rewrite it using one of your suggested implementations.

Comment: I wouldn't even spend 1 minute thinking about this, I see horrible stuff all the time. I will literally eat a hat if there's any purpose to that approach and that's a promise. Also, reading answers to this question is going to be a rollercoaster of fail.

Comment: When dealing with user input, I am a fan of `bool Int32.TryParse(string, out int)`

Comment: @JLRishe - No, not able to get in contact with the author of the code, unfortunately.

Comment: That code will through an exception if the string representation of the decimal value contains a decimal point.  Assuming that the `NumericUpDown` is setup for whole numbers then there really is no reason to do it that way instead of what you came up with.

Comment: Is `myNumericUpDown` by any chance a UI control? If so, I've seen similar things arise out habit due to UI elements often giving odd container objects instead of actual decimal values. If so, sometimes someone will convert the object to a `String` since `.toString()` is always available and then parse as necessary. Still seems pretty silly

Comment: @juharr, you're right... that makes it even weirder.

Comment: @Sam - Yes, it's a [System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  I suppose that does sound plausible enough.

Comment: Also, don't use `(int)` cast, use `ToInt32` because the first one will floor the value so 1.9999 will be 1.

Comment: Ah. Stringly-typed code. It's definitely an anti-pattern. Because (the author) forces everything to be a string at some point during it's journey through the system, they ensure that anything that *could* have been a compiler error is instead a runtime error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course we cannot look into the mind of the programmer who wrote that code initially, but doing numeric conversions through strings is quite common with newer programmers. Presumably they first wrote

```
int myIntValue = myNumericUpDown.Value
```

got a compiler error, found `Int32.Parse` and put the pieces together.

There is really *no* reason *at all* to convert it to a string first, and then parse an integer from that - if anything it is inefficient and awkward to read.

In fact note that if for whatever reason the `ToString` gives an actual decimal number (like `3.0` instead of `3`) the code will throw a `System.FormatException` which is not caught. From the assumption that you are not seeing that exception when running, I deduce that the control is set such that the `Value` property is always an integer, never something like `1.932`, hence I would argue that the fastest way to get it as an integer is a hard cast

```
int myIntValue = (int)myNumericUpDown.Value;
```

(and add a `try/catch` for the inevitable case that your form designer messes up and sets the initial value of the control to `0.5`).

Comment: int-casting a decimal with a fractional part won't throw an exception. It will just round toward zero. And I agree with bokibeg's assertion that `Convert.ToInt32()` would generally be preferable.